# Convert time series format

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, powerquery, vlookup

I have a dataset (df) of time series as follow:

```
date          symbol   close
09/01/2018    ACA      132.1
10/01/2018    ACA      134.4
...
28/04/2013    BA       22.12
...
21/01/2016    DIL      180.01
...
```

The idea was to convert it as this:

```
date          ACA      BA      DIL
28/04/2013    NaN      22.12   NaN
...
21/01/2016    NaN      23      180.01
...
...
...
10/01/2018    134.4    32.2    181.3
```

So taking the longest period of time on first column, and match the close price on the others. I guess it can be done with `VLOOKUP()` or `MATCH()` somehow.

Any idea?

Comment: Even though you provided examples of original data and desired result it is still hard to grasp the concept of what you're trying to achieve. Can you clarify it a bit more?

Comment: Probably worth trying a few things and when you get stuck ask a specific question.

Comment: I solved how to subset, so I deleted the second part. As regard the first one, I just want to rearrange from Example 1 to Example 2. So from the oldest to the newest date keeping different column for each time series.

Comment: Where's the `23` and `32, 2` under `BA`  come from on the bottom table?   I can't see how the top table can convert to the bottom table - thought I did, but not everything has been converted.... is that by design?

Comment: Oh no, it's just a matter of formatting decimal numbers that comma `,`. That's how the italian excel version threat them. Consider it as 32.2, it's exactly the same. I'm gonna change it now to avoid further confusion.

Comment: @toyo10 I think what Darren meant to say is that the values `32.2`, `181.3` and `23` that appear in your result (lower example), do not appear in your datatset (upper example). So how can we know where they come from? It is very hard to understand what your actual goal is because your data and example is not consistent. Try to be as precise as possible with your description and your examples. So Eg. *"taking the longest period of time on first column"* is very unclear! I don't see where you take a period of time from?

Comment: Posting the same questing repeatedly is against [so] policies.  Please remove one.

Comment: Gotcha. That value does not appear in the dataset since they are under the `...`. I reported the starting values (132.1 in 09/01/2018 for ACA, 22.12 in 28/04/2013 for BA and  180.01 in 21/01/2016 for DIL) but the database contain many different values up to today for each series. In the example I just showed how the data set would be i.e. ordered by date. To make it clear I added some values I don't posted in the first example. I'm gonna add them in the example for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Powerquery.

Step 1: Select a populated cell in your data range  Goto PowerQuery tab if pre Excel 2016 (and have installed the free-add in) or Data tab in 2016 > Data  > Get & Transform > from table

[image: Select a cell then Data > From table]

Step 2: Make sure `date` column is formatted as Date

[image: Date column]

Step 3: Order `date` column in ascending order

[image: Ascending column sort]

Step 4: Select `symbol` column > Transform tab > Pivot column

[image: Select column and choose pivot column]

Ensure that values part is using `Close`

[image: Values using Close for pivot on Symbol column]

Step 5: Re-arrange columns as required

[image: Re-arranged columns]

Step 6: Close and ***load to page***

[image: Close and load (choose lower option of too page)]

Note: You do not replace Null with NaN. When exported to sheet these cells will be blank.

M Code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"date", type date}, {"symbol", type text}, {"close", type number}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type",{{"date", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Sorted Rows", List.Distinct(#"Sorted Rows"[symbol]), "symbol", "close", List.Sum),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"date", "ACA", "BA", "DIL"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```