# Time series dataset Subset

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I have a dataset as follow:

```
date          ACA      BA      DIL     ...
28/04/2013    NaN      22.12   NaN     ...
...
21/01/2016    NaN      23      180.01  ...
...
...
...
10/01/2018    134.4    32.2    181.3   ...
```

What if I would like to subset the column for a specific list? For example let's say my list encompass ACA and DIL, to obtain:

```
date          ACA      DIL     ...
28/04/2013    NaN      NaN     ...
...
21/01/2016    NaN      180.01  ...
...
...
...
10/01/2018    134.4    181.3   ...
```

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question yesterday?

Comment: You would use *MATCH()* to find the proper column and then *INDEX()* to retrieve data from that column.

Comment: ...so you need to delete the BA column?  That's the only difference between the two examples.

Comment: .@ashleedawg yes in this example. In reality I have 1000+ to subset from and a list of 300+.

Comment: @toyo - First off, posting the [same question repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50022087/convert-time-series-format-and-subset-it) is against [so] policy. Please delete one.  Secondly, you need to include sample data that is actually **representative** of the actual data.  Following posting tips and guidelines such as "[mcve]" and "[ask]" will give you **far better chances of finding a solution that repeated posting will** (and will be far less likely to cause upset with your actions).

Comment: @ashleedawg it is not the same question. I thought it was clear but since it was not, I'm gonna provide a better example.

Comment: @CFO - good memory - but did you know you can check that?  This kind of self moderation is important on such a busy site

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert time series format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50022087/convert-time-series-format)

Comment: Ok, one last time....just because I provided the same dataset example it does not mean the question is the same. You can actually do many things on the same dataset. By the way, thank you for your engagement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say on *Sheet1* we have data like:

[image]

On *Sheet2* place the subset headers in the first row.  Then in *Sheet2* cell **A2** enter:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$K$20,ROW(),MATCH(A$1,Sheet1!$A$1:$K$1,0))
```

The *MATCH()* locates the proper column in the source data, the *INDEX()* gets the data.  Copy this formula both across and down to get:

[image]

Modify the table addresses in the formula to match your actual data.

Comment: It was exactly what I needed!

Comment: @toyo10  Glad to help